# Disable jQuery for some pages but keep the styles?

Tags: jquery, html, navbar

Hi I'm making a mobile website with jquery, And I want to disable jQuery on some pages but still keep the styles i.e. the nav bar and everything, is this possible? Thanks
p.s. The reason I want it disabled is so I can use anchors :)

Comment: you can use anchors **with** jquery included...

Comment: no you cant when you use certainpage.html#part-of-page it wont work, i'm talking about external anchors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery Mobile? If I understand you correctly, you can just remove the lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js">
```

And keep the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

Comment: I i tried that but then it disables my jQuery navigation bar.

Comment: So you want jQuery disabled, but you still want jQuery to work? I think you should open a new question asking how to get anchors to work while using jQuery Mobile, that seems to be your real problem

Comment: Okay, sorry I guess my question got kind of confusing.